# How to make php-debug extension for Atom work on wampserver

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, xdebug, atom-editor

I have failed to install this on ubuntu before, now for Windows I don't understand [this documentation](https://atom.io/packages/php-debug) properly.

---

What I have done is:

- I set up WampServer, upgraded to 3.0.8, installed its own XDebug. When I phpinfo(), I see that XDebug is installed.
- I installed [php-debug](https://atom.io/packages/php-debug) package for Atom.
- I couldn't find out where should I put the codes (below) so I put it inside php.ini which is in `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.5`

> ```
> xdebug.remote_enable=1
> xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
> xdebug.remote_connect_back=1    # Not safe for production servers
> xdebug.remote_port=9000
> xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
> xdebug.remote_mode=req
> xdebug.remote_autostart=true
> ```

- PHP Debug console on Atom doesn't allow me to press buttons. Putting breakpoints doesn't affect anything at all. PHP Console on Atom only says this: `Listening on Port 9000` `Closed`

Comment: WAMPServer comes **WITH XDEBUG ALREADY INSTALLED AND CONFIGURED**

Comment: If you edited `\wamp\bin\php\php7.1.5` then you amended the `php.ini` file that is used ONLY by the PHP CLI (Command Line Interface)

Comment: Use the wampmanager menus to edit the `php.ini` file used with Apache... `wampmanager->PHP->php.ini` This will open the correct `php.ini` file. **Which already contains the XDEBUG parameters you tried to add to the wrong `php.ini` file** Just look at the last few lines of the correct `php.ini` file

Comment: `wampmanager->PHP->php.ini` opens up as an untitled file with no extension.

Comment: Then try a refresh... `(right click)wampmanager->refresh` to rebuild the symlinks

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable debugging with a cookie on the browser side. You do that using a shortcut button or browser add on. Once you have that, you can toggle debugging on or off.

Give this one a try, if you are on firefox. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/the-easiest-xdebug/

I use PHPStorm, so it might be different in Atom, but I also click a 'listen for incoming connections' button. Look for one of those, and toggle it in Atom.

Comment: I use the one for the Chrome. Inside cookies I can see XDebug. I start debugging but nothing else. Nothing on Php Console on atom (which I am trying to do that's why I choose not to use Chrome/Firefox plugin for this.) Nothing on Chrome Inspector.

On atom there are buttons `Continue` `Step Over` `Step In` `Step Out` `Stop` but none of them are clickable.